# Migration from mq version 7.0 to 7.5

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms, ibm-mq, weblogic11g

I am Migrating from Mq version 7.0 to 7.5 . I am able to receive messages through the inbound queues using ejb - Message Driven Beans(MDBs) but while posting the message after processing it on the. I am getting the IBM MQRC 2082 MQRC_UNKOWN_ALIAS_BASE_Q Exception.

This is the exception that I am getting :

> Caused by: javax.jms.InvalidDestinationException: MQJMS2008: failed to
>   open MQ queue 'OFS.TIG_IND2NSE_MSG'.
>           at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jms.internal.MQQueueServices.getQueueOpenException(MQQueueServices.java:901)
>           at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jms.internal.MQQueueServices.getOutputQueue(MQQueueServices.java:727)
>           at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jms.internal.JMSServicesMgr.getOutputQueue(JMSServicesMgr.java:210)
>           at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jms.internal.MQSession.createQProducer(MQSession.java:3138)
>           at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jms.internal.MQSession.createProducer(MQSession.java:2863)
>           at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jms.internal.MQSession.createProducer(MQSession.java:2920)
>           at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.createProducer(JmsSessionImpl.java:1191)
>           at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsXAQueueSessionImpl$1.createSender(JmsXAQueueSessionImpl.java:415)
>           at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueSession.createSender(MQQueueSession.java:148)
>           at weblogic.deployment.jms.WrappedSession.createSender(WrappedSession.java:344)
>           at com.tiger.gmfs.framework.jms.QUtil.getSender(QUtil.java:216)
>           at com.tiger.gmfs.framework.jms.QUtil.sendMessage(QUtil.java:110)

The piece of code that i wrote is :
this is my getSender method:
protected QueueSender getSender() throws JavaMessagingException,
            JMSException {

```
    QueueSender sender = null;
    queue = qsess.createQueue(qVO.getName());
    sender =  qsess.createSender(queue);
    if (sender == null)
        throw new JavaMessagingException("The queue sender is null.");


    sender.setPriority(qVO.getPriority());
    return sender;
}
```

and this is my sendMessage method:

```
public void sendMessage(Message jmsMessage) throws JavaMessagingException,
            JMSException {
        QueueSender sender = null;
        try {
            sender = getSender();
            sender.send(jmsMessage);
        } catch (JMSException j) {
            Exception l = j.getLinkedException();
            if (l != null) {
                JavaMessagingException be = new JavaMessagingException(
                        "JMSErrCode:" + l + " Code:" + j.getErrorCode()
                                + " Message: " + jmsMessage, j);
                throw be;
            } else
                throw new JavaMessagingException(j);
        }catch(Exception e1){
            System.out.println(e1);
        }finally {

            if (sender != null) {
                sender.close();
                TracingHelper.infoLog(QUtil.class, "sendMessage",
                        "Closed sender");
            }
        }
    }
```

**What changes should i do here that my code works?**

**I have Implemented the same code in jre 1.7 +weblogic 12c that works perfectly but when i changed it to jre 1.6 + weblogic 11g, i get this error.**

Comment: What is the version of the MQ queue manager you're using? And what is the version of the MQ client you're using in weblogic? Are you using the MQ JCA RA?

Comment: MQ Client version is 7.0 +Weblogic 11g +No we are not using MQ JCA RA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a development point of view, when an application opens the queue - the developer has to make sure that the right open options are used to open a WebSphere MQ queue.

If the application wants to put a message, open the queue with MQOO_OUTPUT open option and not any of the MQOO_INPUT* options.

If the application wants to get a message, open the queue with any one of the below open options, but not all at the same time
MQOO_INPUT_SHARED
MQOO_INPUT_EXCLUSIVE
MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF

The reason being, if the queue being opened is an alias queue pointing to a base queue in the same queue manager where the alias queue is present, and the base queue is a local queue - both, the OUTPUT and INPUT open options are valid.

However, if the alias queue being opened is pointing to a remote queue or a topic in the same queue manager where the alias queue is present, or if the alias queue is pointing to a cluster local queue present in a different queue manager in the cluster, all of the MQOO_INPUT* open options are invalid in this scenario.

Hence it is always advisable to open a WebSphere MQ queue only and only with the appropriate open options required for the operation being performed.

In your case, if you are trying to open the alias queue with any of the MQOO_INPUT* open option, and it is pointing to a cluster local queue in a different queue manager, it is incorrect. You have to remove the MQOO_INPUT* open option from your code to resolve the issue, as the MQOO_INPUT* option is not valid in this scenario.

Comment: sir :@Vinay sir : any comments on this link :

[link] https://www.mail-archive.com/mqseries@akh-wien.ac.at/msg14002.html...

I think my application while initializing the QueueConnectionFactory at the startup sets the QueueManager name ... it works good for the inbound that MDBs but while posting the message it again uses the same QueueManager name as explicitly set . But acording to this link the queue manager name should be used blank as the base queue is in the remote queue manager . whenever it tries to check for the Queue Manager it fails ....Please do comment...

Comment: Yes, if your application uses JMS, ignoring or keeping the queue manager name blank on message producers will help resolving the issue. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

MQRC 2082 MQRC_UNKOWN_ALIAS_BASE_Q is telling you that the queue in question:-

```
MQJMS2008: failed to open MQ queue 'OFS.TIG_IND2NSE_MSG'.
```

is an alias queue that isn't defined correctly, because the base queue it is pointing at doesn't exist.

Suggest you use the following MQSC command to display it:-

```
DISPLAY QALIAS(OFS.TIG_IND2NSE_MSG) ALL
```

and look for the field `TARGET`, and then issue another MQSC command to display the queue it is aliasing:-

```
DISPLAY QUEUE(target-queue-name) ALL
```

which I expect will fail telling you the queue doesn't exist. In that case you should either define it, or correct the `QALIAS` definition to point at the correct target queue name.

Comment: The case here is - the user is trying to open an alias queue with (MQC.MQOO_INPUT*) which is pointing to a cluster local queue in a different queue manager. The application has to open only for PUT (MQOO_OUTPUT) and not GET, which resolves the issue.

If I run amqsputc on the same alias queue, it just works fine and resolves the cluster queue. If i run amqsgetc, i get 2082, as the base queue is not present in the local queue manager where the alias is present.

Comment: From IBM PMR
-----------------------------------

Open options: 0x00000022
 
 MQOO_INPUT_SHARED              0x00000002
 MQOO_INQUIRE                   0x00000020

 
 08:59:07.728611  --}! kqiSetupQPath rc=krcE_OPTION_NOT_VALID_FOR_TYPE
 08:59:07.728615  --}! kqiOpenQueue rc=krcE_OPTION_NOT_VALID_FOR_TYPE
 
The following options are not allowed with the topic.
 
 MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF
 MQOO_INPUT_SHARED
 MQOO_INPUT_EXCLUSIVE
 MQOO_BROWSE
 
Please also note MQOO_INPUT* options are also not allowed on an object
that resolves to a cluster queue that is not defined locally.
----------end----------

Comment: @VinaySathyanarayana Your comments would make a good answer text, why don't you write an answer with them, then it can be accepted as the correct answer too if appropriate. Sounds like there may be other information to add into the question too? You can always edit the question to add that to it.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is for an alias when the Base Queue Manager is present at the cluster or some other Remote Queue manager. setting the Queuemanger name explicitly will give this error.
    if(jmsConfigQueue.getOpenOptions()!=null){
        if(jmsConfigQueue.getOpenOptions().equalsIgnoreCase("Inbound")) 
        {
            mqqueue.setBaseQueueManagerName(qcf.getQueueManager());
        }
        else if(jmsConfigQueue.getOpenOptions().equalsIgnoreCase("Outbound"))
        {
            mqqueue.setBaseQueueManagerName("");
        }
        else
            mqqueue.setBaseQueueManagerName(qcf.getQueueManager());
    }
    else {
        mqqueue.setBaseQueueManagerName(qcf.getQueueManager());
    }

So to enable the application search the Base Queue Manager(Remote) set it as blank. as the above code.